# Error: NJS-510 connection to host x port x timed out. Request exceeded "transportConnectTimeout" of 60 seconds

Tags: oracle, express

I wrote the code below as a route implement. The pool connected to database successfully when the process go through the first try clause which is using await db.connectToDatabase();.

However, when the code reaches pool.getConnection, the process doesn't get in the code and reported a Error:NJS-510. Below is my route code:

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const db = require("../db")

//Oracle connect pool

let pool;
route.get("/chooseUser", async (req, res) ={
let sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = ?";
let params = ["john.doe@example.com"];
console.log("getUser", req.query);
db.connectSSH();
    //http://localhost:9000/foodItemInspection?id=1&name=2
try {
Ensure the database is connected
await db.connectToDatabase();
Get the pool
pool = db.getPool();

catch (err) {
console.error('Database error:', err);
    }
console.log("getUser:", req.query);

    //search the food item based on food's information
    //An error happened here. The process didnt even go through this method
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
if (err) throw err
connection.query(sql, params, function(queryError, results, fields) {
db.disconnectFromDatabase();
console.log(1);
if(queryError) {
console.error('Query error:', queryError);
return res.status(500).render('error', { error: queryError });
            }

console.log(results);
Return the information with EJS rendering, this render has a huge problem
res.render('userChoose', { users: results });
        });
    });

})

module.exports = route; //expose
```

And this is my db.js code (the config.mysql is not a problem here. I just forgot to change the name I used in config.js):

```javascript
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const configs = require('./config')

const con = new Client();
console.log('initializing：', configs);
console.log('initializing：', configs.sshConfig.port);



function connectSSH() {
const con = new Client();

con.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Connection :: ready');
con.shell(function(err, stream) {
if (err) {
console.log('err over ')
else {
connectToDatabase();
var buf = '';
var bData = false;
stream.on('data', function(data) {

if (bData == false) {
bData = true;
stream.write('su\n');
                    }
if (data.indexOf('Password:') > -1) {
stream.write('Pxxxxxxxx')
                    }
console.log(data.toString())
if (data.indexOf('# ') > -1) {
console.log('successful')
stream.end()
                    }
                }).on('close', function() {
console.log('success over ')
                }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
                });
            }
        });
    });

con.on('error', (err) => {
console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
    });

con.on('end', () => {
console.log('Connection :: end');
    });

con.on('close', (had_error) => {
console.log('Connection :: close');
    });

Start the connection
con.connect(configs.sshConfig);
return con; // Returning the connection object might be useful
}


con.connect({
host: configs.sshConfig.host,
port: configs.sshConfig.port,
username: configs.sshConfig.username,
password: configs.sshConfig.password
})

let pool;
async function connectToDatabase() {
try {
const dbConfig = {
user: configs.mysql.user, 
password: configs.mysql.password, 
connectString: 'myConnectString', 
        };


pool = await oracledb.createPool(dbConfig);
console.log('Connected to the remote Oracle database successfully.');
catch (err) {
console.error('Error connecting to the remote Oracle database:', err);
finally {

    }
}

async function disconnectFromDatabase() {
if (pool) {
try {
await pool.close();
console.log('Database connection closed successfully.');
catch (err) {
console.error('Error closing the database connection:', err);
throw err; // Optionally re-throw the error for the caller to handle
        }
    }

if (con) {
con.end(); // Assuming con.end() is the correct way to close your SSH connection
console.log('SSH tunnel connection closed');
    }
}

function closeSSH() {
if (con) {
con.end(); // Close the SSH connection
console.log('SSH tunnel connection closed');
    }
}

module.exports = {
connectToDatabase,
getPool: () => pool, // Expose a getter for the pool
disconnectFromDatabase,
connectSSH,
closeSSH
};
```

This is the first time I ask a question on stack overflow. I am sorry if my question is not clarified enough or formatted well. Thanks for all your guys' help!

Comment: I've removed the quotes and changed to code blocks. Please [edit] the question and ensure that your code is indented properly so that it is easily readable. Please also ensure that the question is a [MRE] and remove any code that is not relevant to the question so that we can focus only on the relevant parts.

Comment: Fundamentally you have some network issue, possibly caused by the tunnel.  Start debugging by rewriting your code to consistently use async/await (and try blocks) instead of mixing in callbacks.  Read the [node-oracledb doc on pooling](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pooling) to understand the difference between closing a connection and closing a pool.